# getopt command partially parsing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a part of bash script which suppose to do validate the arguments, if it matches then proceed or else exit.
Here is my script

```
TEMP=`getopt --options b,t:,h,n,v,z: --longoptions batch,targetdir:,help,notar,verbose,zone: --name 'mysql-backup-start' -- "$@"`    
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then  
  echo "Command Incoorect"  
  exit 1  
fi
```

`mysql-backup-start` should take the following arguments: `-b`, `-t`, `-h`, `-n`, `-v`, `-z` `--targetdir`, `--help`, `--notar`, `--verbose`, and `--zone`. However, if i pass arguments like `-nn`, `-hh`, or `--tar` it works and it's not supposed to work.

To be more precise what i want, if i execute    **'mysql-backup-start'** should work, **'mysql-  backup-start --notar'** should work,  **'mysql-backup-start --n'** should not work,  **'mysql-backup-start --targetdir=/home/backup/mysql'**  should work, **'mysql-backup-start --targetsdir=/home/backup/mysql'** should not work, **'--mysql-backup-start --ta=/home/backup/mysql'**  should not work.

Comment: Can you run that code passing one/two args, **print $TEMP** and post the output?

Comment: output of $TEMP is --notar --m if i execute mysql-backup-start --notar ,  for mysql-backup-start -nn  its --

Comment: So if you run as **mysql-backup-start  --notar**, then **$TEMP** has **--notar --m --**? For **mysql-backup-start -nn** its **--** and not **-n -n**?

Comment: As posted, that is not a Bash script. Can you include the shebang line or how you run it?

Comment: Could you add your `getopt --version`, please?

Comment: To be more precise what i want, if i execute **'mysql-backup-start'**  should work, '**mysql-backup-start --notar**' should work, '**mysql-backup-start --n**' should not work, '**mysql-backup-start --targetdir=/home/backup/mysql**' should work, '**mysql-backup-start --targetsdir=/home/backup/mysql**' should not work, '**--mysql-backup-start --ta=/home/backup/mysql**' should not work.

Comment: getopt is a generic command line parsing utility, as such it guesses options as long as they aren't ambiguous. And most of the times its correct. Ex. **mysql-backup-start --n** will be valid, as there is a long option **--notar** & there is no other long option starting with "n" to cause ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `-nn`, `getopt` just interprets it as if you'd specified `-n -n`. This is often a valid way to pass arguments - For example, `ssh -vvv` runs with a much higher verbosity level than `ssh -v`. In other commands you have options to enable or disable features, and the last option (enable or disable) "wins." This is useful for example if the user has defined an alias like `alias grep='grep -H'` ("Print the file name for each match."), but wants to override it. To do that she could either run `command grep` or simply revert the option by running `grep -h` which is then resolved to `grep -H -h`.

If you want to check that an option has not been specified more than once (although this is usually not necessary), you should do that later when parsing `$TEMP`.

`--tar` *should* <strike>not</strike> work - See @tuxuday's comment and `man getopt`.

Comment: mysql-backup-start --tar=/home/backup/mysql/
TEMP
--targetdir '/home/backup/mysql/' --
TEMP
--targetdir '/home/backup/mysql/' --

Comment: Please post these as part of the question, and format them as code. It's easier to read there.

Comment: mysql-backup-start --tar=/home/backup/mysql/  TEMP --targetdir     '/home/backup/mysql/'    -- TEMP --targetdir '/home/backup/mysql/'

Comment: To be more precise what i want, if i execute **'mysql-backup-start'**  should work, '**mysql-backup-start --notar**' should work, '**mysql-backup-start --n**' should not work, '**mysql-backup-start --targetdir=/home/backup/mysql**' should work, '**mysql-backup-start --targetsdir=/home/backup/mysql**' should not work, '**--mysql-backup-start --ta=/home/backup/mysql**' should not work.

Comment: getopt takes abbreviated long option names as long as they aren't ambiguous. As such **--tar DIR** is valid.